# Pandas stacked bar chart issue

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have a Dataframe `dft` with two columns `'DATE'` and `'INVOICE'` that looks like the following but with far more rows spanning over a number of years.

```
        DATE      INVOICE

0   2015-01-29    68.61 
1   2015-01-15    16.54 
2   2015-01-15     4.72 
3   2015-01-14    109.71
```

I first sorted this data by `INVOICE` size to give three separate dataframes.

```
small = dft[(dft['INVOICE'] < 25) & 
(dft['INVOICE'] > 0)]

 medium = dft[(dft['INVOICE'] <= 60) & 
(dft['INVOICE'] >= 25)]

large = dft[(dft['INVOICE'] > 60)]
```

I then summed up the total invoice spend in each category for each month and converted this to a list:

```
periods = dft.DATE.dt.to_period("M")

small1 = small.groupby(periods).sum().reset_index()
medium1 = medium.groupby(periods).sum().reset_index()
large1 = large.groupby(periods).sum().reset_index()

# Convert Dataframes to lists for plotting
x1 = small1['DATE'].tolist()
x2 = medium1['DATE'].tolist()
x3 = large1['DATE'].tolist()

y1 = small1['INVOICE'].tolist()
y2 = medium1['INVOICE'].tolist()
y3 = large1['INVOICE'].tolist()
```

To finally plot a stacked bar chart of month and year e.g. (2015-01) against the cumulative invoice size for that month.
My problem is this bar chart gives an error since the y lists are of different sizes.

```
indexes = np.arange(len(x1))

p3 = plt.bar(indexes, y1 + y2 + y3)
p2 = plt.bar(indexes, y2 + y1)
p1 = plt.bar(indexes, y1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Well you certainly don't need to convert the DataFrame to a list for plotting. Can you explain exactly what you are plotting against what? You likely just need to manipulate the DataFrame before plotting to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - Please see edit for details of plotting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think there is an issue with how small, medium and large invoices are being classified. The classification needs to be done within the dataframe, and think about assigning tags for each invoice type.

here is the classification step:

```
def invoice_classifier(amount):
    if amount < 25 and amount > 0: return 'small'
    elif amount <= 60: return 'medium'
    elif amount > 60: return 'large'
# for each row assign a class
df['invoice_class'] = df.apply(lambda r: invoice_classifier(r['INVOICE']), axis=1)

# plotting
df.groupby(by=['DATE', 'invoice_class'])['INVOICE'].sum().unstack('invoice_class').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

This should be what you are looking for.

edit:

user wanted month grouping as well.

```
df['month_dates'] = df['dates'].dt.to_period('M')
df.groupby(by=['month_dates', 'invoice_class'])['INVOICE'].sum().unstack('invoice_class').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a very good answer! This however doesn't do the year/month grouping, just plots the sum for each individual date.

Comment: That is trivial, have added it now :)

Comment: @JeevanKumar, very nice one +1.